# Syntax error: "do" unexpected (expecting "}")

Tags: bash

I'm trying to figure out how to do a repeating question and what I have is imposing some issues I believe regarding the function brackets.

```
options.sh: 8: options.sh: Syntax error: "do" unexpected (expecting "}")
```

Here is the sample

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # v0.1 b1 3/30/2016

    # REPEATING FUNCTIONS

    ramdisk_memory() {
      echo -e "\nRAMDISK SETTINGS\n"
      echo -e "Enter the size of the RAMDISK in megabytes:"
      read ramsize
      echo -e "You selected a size of ${ramsize} megabytes. Is this correct?"
      select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
          case $yn in
              Yes ) setup_ramdisk ramsize; break;;
              No ) ramdisk_memory; break;;
          esac
      done
    }

    setup_ramdisk() {
      echo "You did it!"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call your script with `sh options.sh`, the bash shebang will be overriden with a call to `/bin/sh` that does not support `select`. You can either call your script with :

- `bash options.sh`
- or make it executable with `chmod u+x options.sh` and invoke it with `./options.sh`

Comment: Oh, I inadvertently found this out just recently with another problem after I had devised another method. Thank you!